# Why the partial derivative is $0$ when $F_{ij}^l < 0$?. Math behind style transfer

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, relu, calculus, vgg, style-transfer

I am currently in the process of reading and understanding the process of style transfer. I came across this equation in the research paper which went like -
[image]

For context, here is the paragraph -

> Generally each layer in the network defines a non-linear
> filter bank whose complexity increases with the position of
> the layer in the network. Hence a given input image is
> encoded in each layer of the Convolutional Neural Network
> by the filter responses to that image. A layer with $N_l$ distinct filters has $N$ feature maps each of size $M$ , where $M_l$
> is the height times the width of the feature map. So the re-
> sponses in a layer l can be stored in a matrix $Fl ∈ R^{N_l×M_l}$
> where F l is the activation of the ith filter at position j in ij
> layer l.
> To visualise the image information that is encoded at
> different layers of the hierarchy one can perform gradient descent on a white noise image to find another image that matches the feature responses of the original image (Fig 1, content reconstructions). Let $\vec p$ and $\vec x$ be the original image and the image that is generated, and $P^l$ and $F^l$ their respective feature representation in layer l. We then define the squared-error loss between the two feature representations
> $\mathcal{L_{content}(\vec p, \vec x, l)} = {1\over 2} \Sigma_{i,j} \big(F_{ij}^l - P_{ij}^l \big)$. The derivative of this loss with respect to the activations in layer $l$ [***the equation above*** $(2)$].

I just want to know why the partial derivative is $0$ when $F_{ij}^l < 0$.

Comment: Hello. Please, put your **specific** question in the title. "Math behind style transfer" is very vague/general and not a question. Thank you!

Comment: K I actually tried to sum up my entire Q in that one line - wasnt able to in the beginning XD. I'll do it soon

Answer (score 2):

$F_l$ is the activation of the filter. They state in the paper that they base their method on VGG-Network, which uses ReLU as its activation function. In fact, VGG uses it in all of its hidden layers. ReLU is defined as

$$f(x) = max(0,x)$$

Since ReLU is 0 for all x's below 0, the equation above holds; When x is non-positive, all terms in the loss function are constants with respect to $F_{ij}^l$.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks!